# Hibernate. Optimistic lock. Selects version even though it generates it

Tags: java, hibernate, optimistic-locking

I have an entity:

```
<class name="name.dargiri.model.Entity" table="ENTITY" optimistic-lock="version">
  <version name="version" column="ver" type="long" />
</class
```

If the Entity is saved no matter how many times, in the *end of transaction* Hibernate selects for the version of the object. Why? Hibernate generates this version when it stores the object, so it knows it. I found out that this method invokes this:

```
EntityVerifyVersionProcess#getCurrentVersion()
```

Hibernate generates this in logs:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* update
        name.dargiri.model.Entity */ update
            ENTITY 
        set
            ver=?,
            USERNAME=?,
            lucky_number=? 
        where
            id=? 
            and ver=?
Hibernate: 
    /* get version name.dargiri.model.Entity */ select
        ver 
    from
        ENTITY 
    where
        id =?
```

I use MySQL and Session#save().

Comment: I thought a bit and recalled that I don't flush after first save. Will try flushing after each update, may be this will result in select after each save().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so what I didn't write about and what appeared to be the problem is using LockMode.OPTIMISTIC:
`session.get(Entity.class, 1L, LockMode.OPTIMISTIC);`

It appeared that this is how this lock mode works - it checks at the end of the transaction whether no one changed the version of the object so far. And this happens not while flushing, because Hibernate will anyway do the check, but by the end of the transaction, which is, I think, additional option to be more careful about overwriting data.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate performs an extra SQL statement to retrieve the version number after the update has been made because the version number is managed by the database. For more details, I suggest you take a look at this [article](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/post/Versioning-Optimistic-Locking-in-Hibernate.aspx) which explains this very well.

Comment: Take a closer look at that article. The select happens only if generated="always". It's not my case. Moreover even if it was that case, Hibernate would perform select after each update, not while transaction commit.

Comment: Oops, didn't pay close enough attention. My bad... What method do you actually use to save the entity into DB?

Comment: That's weird : I've just created a project to do pretty much the same thing as you did (except that I configured my domain model using JPA annotations instead of Hibernate mapping files) and the logs show that only an INSERT statement is executed.

Comment: Maybe is has something to do with the database the application is running against. What DB are you using? In my test, I've used Derby

Comment: Well, it's possible that JPA and native Hibernate have different default behavior. But from your words - you just insert the new record, and what about reading the existing one and then updating it? I use MySQL.

Comment: Same goes for reading + updating the entity : the logs show that only an UPDATE statement is executed